# Running multiple code lines in a R function

Tags: r

I would like to run some code lines in a function. Is there a easy way to run multiple code lines in R, so i don't need to run one code line after another?
For example like the void method in Java?

```
a() {
data$Item <- gsub(" Grams ", "g ", data$Item);
data$Item <- gsub("Grams ", "g ", data$Item);
data$Item <- gsub(" GRAMS ", "g ", data$Item);
data$Item <- gsub("GRAMS ", "g ", data$Item);
data$Item <- gsub("grams", "g ", data$Item);
data$Item <- gsub("Grams", "g ", data$Item);
}
```

If i run a() like that all commands are done but it also says ->

```
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think the error is due to the fact that you have a semicolon after your last line, so R is expecting another function,but you gave it the closing bracket instead. If you remove the last semicolon the error should go away.

Comment: Nope the error message remains. Ty anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put your string in lower case and do a single `gsub()`, and then deal with extra spaces with `trimws()`.

```
data$Item <- gsub("grams", "g ", tolower(data$Item))
```

---

But you can make a function like this:

```
my_function <- function() {
    data$Item <<- gsub(" Grams ", "g ", data$Item)
    data$Item <<- gsub("Grams ", "g ", data$Item)
    data$Item <<- gsub(" GRAMS ", "g ", data$Item)
    data$Item <<- gsub("GRAMS ", "g ", data$Item)
    data$Item <<- gsub("grams", "g ", data$Item)
    data$Item <<- gsub("Grams", "g ", data$Item)
}
my_function()
```

Use the double `<<-` for changing the values globally, and not just inside the function.

Comment: Nice, but try to use `tolower()` when dealing with strings to guarantee you get all the different cases.

Comment: @TheBiro if you are adamant about  using the function instead of the gsub tolower function for code maintenance (perhaps in the future you may want to add additional cases), I would recommend using gsub with a regular expression, such as `data$newItem <- gsub("( +[Gg][Rr][Aa][Mm][Ss]?)"," g",data$item,perl=T)`